# Which kernel to use Gaussian Process Regression on hockey-stick data

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process

I need to create a fit using Gaussian Process Regression for data that looks like a hockey-stick (has a fast decay for x=0 to x=10 and for x>50 it converges to some value).

I tried with all the kernels of the GPy library and I got the following plot. 'RatQuad' fits better for x<10 but for x>40 there are some 'bubbles'. 'Exponential' is the second-best but still not a good fit.

[image]

Here is the code that I use:

```
import GPy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array( [0.3, 1, 3, 7, 13, 21, 30, 52, 72, 100] ).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array( [23, 16, 9, 6, 4.8, 4.1, 3.5, 2.8, 2.4, 2.2] ).reshape(-1,1)

kernels = []
kernels.append( GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=1, lengthscale=1) )
kernels.append( GPy.kern.Exponential(input_dim=1, variance=1, lengthscale=1) )
kernels.append( GPy.kern.Matern32(input_dim=1, variance=1, lengthscale=1) )
kernels.append( GPy.kern.Matern52(input_dim=1, variance=1, lengthscale=1) )
kernels.append( GPy.kern.ExpQuad(input_dim=1, variance=1, lengthscale=1) )
kernels.append( GPy.kern.RatQuad(input_dim=1, variance=1, lengthscale=1) )

labels = ['RBF', 'Exponential', 'Matern32', 'Matern52', 'ExpQuad', 'RatQuad']

plt.scatter( x, y, label ='Data' )
x_plot = np.linspace(0.3, 100, 90).reshape(-1,1)

for kernel, label in zip(kernels, labels):

    GPR_M = GPy.models.GPRegression( x, y, kernel )
    GPR_M.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 30, verbose=False)

    y_plot, _ = GPR_M.predict( x_plot )

    plt.plot( x_plot, y_plot, label=label )
```

Here is a plot with a pink curve showing what I would like to obtain:

[image]

Could you suggest a kernel to get such a fit? GPy or scikit-learn would be both OK for me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you *have* to use GP regression? My worry is that, the GP prediction will go to $0$ outside of the range of the observed data. This means that it will be very tricky to correctly model the asymptote-like behavior seen for small $x$.

Comment: Thanks @jcken for your comment. I am not really interested in extrapolation outside the range of observed data. I do not *have* to, but I'm trying to learn how to apply GPR to model data and I don't understand why no kernel works for this "hockey-stick" data

Comment: The problem is that your data has more than one length scale, close to zero it has a very small length scale (fast change) and close to 100 has a very large length scale (almost constant)